# create object using properties of other object

Tags: javascript

Given these two objects:

firstObject:

```
var firstObject = {
    title: 'value1',
    year: 'value2',
    contributors: 'value3',
    abstract: 'value4'
};
```

secondObject:

```
var secondObject = {
    title: 'Title',
    year: 'Year',
    contributors: 'Contributors',
    abstract: 'Abstract'
};
```

How can I create a third object structured like this?:

```
var thirdObject = {
    Title: 'value1'
    Year: 'value2',
    Contributors: 'value3',
    Abstract: 'value4'
};
```

Basically assigning the properties of the secondObject as the keys of the thirdObject and the properties of the firstObject as the properties of the thirdObject.

**Note:** I don't want any uppercase of the of the firstObject keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that :

```
var firstObject = {
    title: 'value1',
    year: 'value2',
    contributors: 'value3',
    abstract: 'value4'
};

var secondObject = {
    title: 'Title',
    year: 'Year',
    contributors: 'Contributors',
    abstract: 'Abstract'
};

var newObj = {};

$.each(secondObject, function(i){
    newObj[this] = firstObject[i];
});

//Vanilla JS version
for(var x in secondObject){
    newObj[secondObject[x]] = firstObject[x];
}
console.log(newObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kq6tcp5L/

Answer (score 0):

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/b1oxtesj/3/). This assign "" if key doesn't exists in firstObject.

```
  var firstObject = {
        title: 'value1',
        year: 'value2',
        contributors: 'value3',
        abstract: 'value4'
    };

    var secondObject = {
        title: 'Title',
        year: 'Year',
        contributors: 'Contributors',
        abstract: 'Abstract',
        extra:''
    };
    var thirdObject ={};

    for(var key in secondObject)
    {
        if (secondObject.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
          thirdObject[key] = (typeof firstObject[key] === "undefined")?"":firstObject[key];
        }
    }

    console.log(thirdObject);
```